# `method_missing` doesn't work with `prepend`

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am trying to use `Module#prepend` for some hook:

```
module B
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    p 'B method_missing'
    #if condition
    #  do_something
    #else
      super method, *args, &block #I need to call method from A
    #end
  end
end

class A
  prepend B

  def hello
    p 'A hello'
  end
end

A.new.hello #=> "A hello"
```

But I want something like:

```
#=> "B method_missing"
#=> "A hello"
```

But if I call a non-existing method:

```
A.new.baybay #=> "B method_missing" 
#and error `method_missing': undefined method `baybay' for #<A:0x0000000182c430> (NoMethodError)
```

And about ancestors:

```
A.ancestors #=> [B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
A.new.singleton_class.ancestors #=> [#<Class:#<A:0x000000027b6900>>, B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

But if I create a method with the same name:

```
module B
  def hello
    p 'B hello'
  end
end

A.new.hello #=> "B hello"
```

Why is it not working with `method_missing`? How can I get what I want? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that on method invocation, ruby will traverse up the ancestors chain searching for a method with said name. **Only** if such method is not found, a second traversal is done for `method_missing`.

---

A possible solution would be to write `method_missing` in `A` too:

```
module B
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    p 'B method_missing'
    super method, *args, &block
  end
end

class A
  prepend B

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    p 'A hello' if method == :hello
  end
end

A.new.hello # => "B method_missing"
            # => "A hello"
```

---

Another approach, which would not require you to change the `A` class would be to use the [`Module#prepended`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-prepended) hook. Then you can inspect all of the methods in class `A` and use [`Module#define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method).

This would however be unnecessarily complex and I don't see much value in doing it, unless you are writing some sort of framework. Why not just wrap the class instead?